# QC API JAR to connect using java

Tags: java, spring, hp-quality-center

I'm trying to integrate QC (also known as ALM) using **java/servlets/springs** and I've tried the following jar to do it, however I'm not able to establish the connection.

1) "com4j" - which is quite old and is also mentioned on this forum as well, however the latest QC or ALM doesn't gets connected using this jar

[QC Connection from Java using Com4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15403725/qc-connection-from-java-using-com4)

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can someone provide their expertise?

Comment: I prefer to use JRuby to access QC via OTA API from Java. I think it uses Jacob as COM Bridge. If you use some newer version of QC (>=11) you can also consider using the REST API.

Comment: I'm using 64bit machine and QC version is the latest one, so my question is would JRuby work from Java on the latest QC version or shall I go for the REST API approach which I'm currently exploring it.

Answer (score 0):

QC version 10.0 or < 10.0 do not support rest api, also latest version of QC including 11, 11.5 and 12 do not support all of its operations through rest such as design-step create/update/read or tractability links.

OTA api is pure .net based com classes which you can register on windows machine and use c# or vb to expose functionality such as create,update,read operations for various objects (Defect/req/test) via wcf/web services. Inturn in java you just need to call the web service which is exposed by yourself.

There is one issue with OTAClient api, due to which it crashes the dll because of memory allocation problems. Its hard to deal with it in 64x environment. Best approach is to expose functionality through developed web services using iis as iis have auto recovery approach to make it up and running in case dll crashes.

Let me know if you have further questions on this.

Comment: Your most of the basic operation can work with rest api

Comment: Thanks for the assistance.